# Unable to extract Hadoop.tar.gz file on Windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation

I am new to Hadoop, and trying install it on windows 10. However, I couldn't extract the downloaded hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz file into my C drive. I tried several times and it kept giving me the following error.

```
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
Cannot create C:\hadoop-2.8.0\share\doc\hadoop\hadoop-yarn\hadoop-yarn-server\hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice\apidocs\org\apache\hadoop\yarn\server\timeline\security\class-use\TimelineDelegationTokenSecretManagerService.TimelineDelegationTokenSecretManager.html
Severe Error: File creation failed.
```

Anyone can help me out of this? Your help is really appreciated.

Yijing

Comment: You might have better luck trying the Hortonworks or Cloudera VMs just for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop should be install on unix(like Centos or Ubuntu). As your case, I recommend you use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)([download for windows](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.22/VirtualBox-5.2.22-126460-Win.exe)) to get your goal.

Before start, you should know linux and javaSE first.